# how to convert (jpg+mp3) into mp4 or mp4 into (jpg+mp3) in xcode programming

Tags: iphone, mp3, jpeg, mp4

Is is possible to convert (jpg+mp3) into mp4 or mp4 into (jpg+mp3) in xcode programming?
The file type is not necessary to be jpg or mp3, it could be any possible photo file type like jpg, png or bmp, and could be any possible audio file type like wav, caf or mp3.

Coud anyone give me a sample code or the reference documents?

thank you very much!!

Alex Lin

Comment: "Xcode programming"? Do you mean Objective-C? Methinks you've never done any programming before--certainly nothing serious using the Xcode IDE. Is this your first project?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this target Mac Os X, you'll want to use Quicktime/qtkit see the [Quicktime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Note I have no experience with this kind of thing or Quicktime, or Obj-C so these are mostly guesses.

The QTMovie seems to represent an arbitrary movie, to get pictures out you will probably want the [getting Movie Images functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003799) most of thos seem to return NSImage objects, I can't seem to find an authoratative answer on how to write that object to an image file but there are a few potential answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038820/how-to-save-a-nsimage-as-a-new-file). I'm even less sure about audio but I think yo get ask the [QTMovie for its (QT)tracks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-SW36) then you you use the [media function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to determine whether its a video or audio. I'm not sure how to save that audio to a file.