# ARC Error on UIImageJPEGRepresentation

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

Been battling this one for a while.  Basically, I am converting an image into NSData so I can send it to a server.  The code I have used before, but for some reason I am getting an ARC error on this.  The error lands on the line I declare the imageData variable.

NOTE: myImage is handed to the method.

```
- (void)uploadImage:(NSImage *)myImage {

     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);

     // Do something...

}
```

I get an error and two warnings

```
Error: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSData *' is disallowed with ARC
Warning: Implicit declaration of function 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation' is invalid in C99
Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion intializing 'NSData * __strong' with an expression of type 'int'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to include the relevant header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Prior to C99, if you call a function that the compiler hasn't seen a declaration for, it will compile the call as if the function was declared as `int UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`. C99 doesn't allow that, but it seems that the compiler is still applying the old interpretation (or the compiler is in pre-C99 mode; I'm not sure what the default is), hence the ARC error.

Comment: Not that it makes a huge difference, but you'd normally use `#import` rather than `#include`. But yeah, UIKit is probably what's missing.

Comment: It's a Desktop App not iPhone.  Does that matter?

Comment: @JeffreyHunter: Probably not, but I can't say for sure. If the function is declared in a different header in the Mac OS X SDKs, you may have to import something else.

Comment: @JeffreyHunter: Oh, yeah, that does matter. UIKit is iOS-only, so basically anything starting with "UI" won't work on OS X. You have to do a bit more work with NSImage than with UIImage, but [this](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSImageToJPEG) looks like it has what you need.

Comment: On second thought, that's not terribly readable and doesn't get you all the way to an NSData instance. Have a look here instead: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213017/1411506](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213017/1411506).