# How to set an image from UIImagePickerController to UIimages in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

New to coding, I've figured out how to let a user select a photo as their background with the following code

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        backgroundImage.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// Wallpaper function

@IBAction func wallpaperMenuPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And it works, still haven't figured out how to save it but will find out soon.

But, if I have a backgroundImage in all my views, how do I get it to set the same image for all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making use of NSNotificationCenter.

In each of your view controllers where you need to apply the change you listen for a notification:

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.addObserver(self, selector: "UpdateBackgroundImage:", name: "BackgroundImageChanged", object: image)
```

In each of those view controllers you'll need to implement the selector, `UpdateBackgroundImage` in this case.  They would be similar to:

```
func UpdateBackgroundImage(notification: NSNotification) {
    let backgroundImage = notification.userInfo!["image"] as UIImage
    // Your code to assign image to background
}
```

After you save the image you can post a notification:

```
// Right after you assign backgroundImage.image = pickedImage  
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let myDict = [pickedImage, "image"]
nc.postNotificationName("BackgroundImageChanged", object: nil, userInfo: myDict)
```

The nice thing about using `NSNotificationCenter` is that as you add new views that need to update the background images you just add the first bit of code.  You don't need to update the code where you pick the images.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I'm not sure how to implement it?

Comment: Do you know how to persist the image? I know its to do with nsuserdefaults, but as soon as I quit the app, the image reverts to the original

Comment: That's really a separate question.  Here's the answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171901/swift-write-image-from-url-to-local-file

Comment: Oh sorry, Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a `BaseViewController` in which common functionality of your app is there and also take a `imageView` in that.

After that inherit all your viewControllers form `BaseViewController` so that `imageView` also be inherited and you can set it and it will be same all of your viewControllers inherited from `BaseViewController`.

Comment: I can't do that because all my views each have their own controller file, thanks for your help though :)